# Values of base class 0 when accessed from children

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna

I am using Xna3 and I can't get the inheritance principle working.

I have this one class:

```
public class Papa{
  protected int winHeight = 10;
}
```

then I have

```
public class Son:Papa{
   int some = winHeight;
}
```

I also tried base.winHeight. For some reason, when debugging line by line I can see the value of winHeight in the parent to be the value 10 but when jumping in the Son class it is 0.

I guess something is wrong in what I do but all pages I found online seems to say this is the way.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to accomplish here. Your code has `Background` as a type of `Level1` but also have multiple `Background` objects in `Level1`. In turn, when you instantiate `Background`, you are instantiating 5 other `Background` objects in the super. Please revisit the definition and usage of inheritance.

Comment: Yep, I realized that. Well, that was more of a trial as I realized I do not need to inherit as it was just for one variable(...) but I was just trying to get used to it. I got back to a more suitable way afterward.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, I find this code doesn't actually compile in VS2012, with the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Papa.winHeight'".  Are you sure yours compiles?

Your variables are declared as fields with initialisers.  Assuming your code *is* compiling for you, the order in which these initialisers run (between derived and base classes) must be such that `some = winHeight` is occurring before `winHeight = 10`.

I'd recommend that you instead put `Son` initlialisation in a constructor, which will be called after the `Papa` fields are initialised:

```
public class Son : Papa
{ 
   int some; 

   public void Son()
   {
      some = winHeight;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will tell more now, my base class calls the constructor of the Son class via the Initialize function. At that point, I can see that jumping to the Son class, the values that were fine int the base class are all 0 or null. I did not put it because I thought I was doing something trivial but my Papa class has an array of Son objects. I can see the array filled in the papa class but jumping to the Son all goes null and all values turn to 0. Maybe this up and down process is wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you should post your actual failing code, instead of a sample that doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out. My issue was that the child class calls the parent constructor but I did not provide any parameter to the constructor...so my base class was empty.

Comment: If you'd posted that code in the first place, you'd have had your answer an hour earlier.  The update code bears no resemblance to the code you originally posted and exhibits a totally different problem!